# Independence of a line integral from the path

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, differential-geometry, differential-forms

I'd like to understand why this statement is true:

If $C$ is a simple closed smooth curve in the plane $x+y+z=1$, then $$\int_C zdx-2xdy+3ydz$$ depends only on the orientation of $C$ and the area of the region enclosed by $C$ but not on the shape of $C$ or its location in the plane.

What is a criterion I can use to verify this? Am I supposed to apply Stokes' theorem? If so, how exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have

- $\vec F=(z,-2x,3y) \implies \nabla \times \vec F=3i+j-2k$

and

$$(\nabla \times \vec F)\cdot d\vec S=(3i+j-2k)\cdot\frac1{\sqrt3}(i+j+k) \,dS=\frac2{\sqrt3}\,dS$$

Comment: No, you need a unit normal.

Comment: @TedShifrin Oh yes of course! I fix that, Thanks!

Comment: Strictly speaking, Stokes says that $\int_C \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{r}=\int\int_S \operatorname{curl} \vec F \cdot \vec n d S$. But our initial integral is not in the form of the left-hand side. Why is it still equal to the RHS? Or what is $\vec r$ in our case?

Comment: @user538518 We have assumed $\vec F=z\hat i-2x\hat j+3y\hat k$ and $d\vec r=dx \hat i+dy\hat j+dz\hat k$ then $ \vec F \cdot d\vec r=zdx-2xdy+3ydz$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you use Stoke's Theorem.  With Stoke's, this integral becomes
$$\int_S <3,1,-2> \cdot dS$$
And as long as the curve is in the plane the integral reduces to 2 times the enclosed area.

Comment: I've obtained $\nabla \times \vec F=3i+j-2k$, do you confirm your result?

Comment: @gimusi Corrected.  That's what I get for trying to do a curl in my head. :)

Comment: ok I was wondering if my derivation was wrong!

Comment: you need also to change: "the integral reduces to 2 times... "

Comment: Still not right, even with gimusi's comment. You need a unit normal to the plane.

Comment: @TedShifrin, it still reduces to twice the area regardless.

Comment: You're wrong on that. Better rethink carefully!